# ionic framework does not generate source maps, or open browser

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, capacitor

I restarted my mac last night. Now development functions of generating source maps and opening the browser when i use `ionice serve` do not work.  I have no idea why.  The app works fine otherwise:[image]

I am using VS Code 1.63.2
Ionic Framework: 6
Angular: 13.1.1
Capacitor: 3.2.4

Edit: this seems to be a configuration issue with mac, as when i run it on window, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with MS Edge on Mac.  Both Chrome and Safari work as expected.